# A simple airport simulation

Tags: java, queue

I'm simulating an airport with one runway. There are 2 queues for planes waiting to land and waiting to take off. There can only be one plane on the runway at a time, and all planes in the air have to land before any planes take off. Here's what I have so far (there's someone useless variables that I'll be getting rid of later when I'm sure I don't need them):

```
public class Runway<E> {
private LinkedBlockingQueue<Plane> takeoff;
private LinkedBlockingQueue<Plane> landing;
private LinkedBlockingQueue<Plane> runway;
private int planesLanded;
private int planesTookoff;
private double averageTakeOffWait;
private double averageLandWait;
private int totalTakeoffWait;
private int totalLandingWait;
private int planesWaitingToTakeOff;
private int planesWaitingToLand;
private int maxLandingQueueLength;
private int maxTakeOffQueueLength;

public int timeToLand = 5;
public int timeToTakeoff = 4;
public double landingProbability = .1;
public double takeOffProbability = .1;
public int simulationLength = 1440;

public Runway() {
    takeoff = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    landing = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    runway = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    planesLanded = 0;
    planesTookoff = 0;
    averageTakeOffWait = 0;
    averageLandWait = 0;
    totalTakeoffWait = 0;
    totalLandingWait = 0;
    planesWaitingToTakeOff = 0;
    planesWaitingToLand = 0;
    maxLandingQueueLength = 0;
    maxTakeOffQueueLength = 0;
    //reset();
}

public void simulate(int duration, double takeoffRate, double landingRate, int landingTime, int takeoffTime) {
    for(int count = 0; count < duration; count++) {
        if(Math.random() < takeoffRate) {
            Plane p = new Plane(landingTime, takeoffTime, count);
            takeoff.offer(p);
        }
        if(Math.random() < landingRate) {
            Plane p = new Plane(landingTime, takeoffTime, count);
            landing.offer(p);
        }

        if(runway.size() == 0) {
                if(landing.peek() != null) {
                    Plane landingPlane = landing.poll();
                    runway.offer(landingPlane);
                    planesLanded++;
                    int landTimeWaited = count - landingPlane.getArrivalTime();
                    totalLandingWait += landTimeWaited; 
                    runway.poll();
                } else if(takeoff.peek() != null) {
                    Plane takeoffPlane = takeoff.poll();
                    runway.offer(takeoffPlane);
                    planesTookoff++;
                    int takeoffTimeWaited = count - takeoffPlane.getArrivalTime();
                    totalLandingWait += takeoffTimeWaited;
                    runway.poll();
                }
            }
    }
}

public void report() {
    System.out.println(planesLanded + " planes have landed.");
    System.out.println(planesTookoff + " planes have taken off.");
    System.out.println(landing.size() + " planes still waiting to land.");
    System.out.println(takeoff.size() + " planes still waiting to takeoff.");

    System.out.println(1.0*totalTakeoffWait/planesTookoff + " average take off wait time.");
    System.out.println(1.0*totalLandingWait/planesLanded + " average landing wait time."); 

  }

}
```

My problem is that the planes barely ever have to wait to do anything. There are never any planes left in the queues. I know that I have to somehow make it so that 5 "minutes" passes before the next plane does anything, but how do I do that? Here's a test run:

```
Runway myAirport = new Runway();
    myAirport.simulate(1440, .1, .1, 5, 4);
    myAirport.report();

146 planes have landed.
155 planes have taken off.
0 planes still waiting to land.
0 planes still waiting to takeoff.
0.0 average take off wait time.
0.14383561643835616 average landing wait time.
```

Comment: You can use Thread.sleep, it it will make actions take some time. You always do runway.poll right after you add, so maybe before the poll, you can use a sleep. Also, isn't runway size always zero because you use .poll? You could also make it random.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you always clear the runway queue, which means you will always clear the plane you add. What you should do, is use some sort of time to check the update.

```
if(runway.size()==0){
    //decide to get from takeoff or landing, your current choice is always take off
    runway.offer(chosenPlane);
    inUseTime = 100;
}else{
    Plane p = runway.peek();
    if(p.getRunwayTime()>=inUseTime){
        runway.poll();
    } else{
        p.updateRunwayTime();
    }
}
```

In this example, the plane only gets removed from the runway if it has finished its time. That means that more plans can get in the other queues while waiting for the current to finish.